# Why isn't my height/width of an <img> in Reactjs changing?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, css

I have a React Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../css/SomePic.css';

class SomePic extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div><img id="helloworld" alt="hello world"></img></div>
    )
  } 
}

export default SomePic;
```

And here is the basic CSS for it:

```
#helloworld {
  content: url('../images/somepic.jpg'); //this is working
  width: 100px;  //this is NOT working
  height: 100px; //this is NOT working
}
```

Why isn't the CSS able to change the width and height of the img tag? The content: url() code works as the image is displayed, but it is showed as its default width and height, not the 100x100 width and height that I want it to be.

Comment: can you try not wrapping it in a `div`?

Comment: Works here: https://codesandbox.io/s/r7mzlzwjpq - Maybe the issue is somewhere else?

Comment: I found out that removing the `alt` attribute will make CSS sizes applied properly, but I cannot find an explanation for this.

Comment: Thank you, I found out that it works without the "alt" attribute. This is because of the "Accepted" answer below. Also: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/585 this was the reason I did not use "src" attribute to begin with, because it did not work and I couldn't tell why until I just looked it up and found that the create-react-app doesn't play well with images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because an `<img>` tag without content loaded from its `src` attribute should display its `alt` attribute, and most browsers chose to set this tags default `display` property to `inline` in this case.

When you use the CSS `content` property to display your image, the `<img>` tag is still in its *alt-fallback mode*, and thus, still displayed *inline*.

To fix it, two solutions:

- Don't use this `content` property anywhere else than on `::after` and `::before` pseudo elements and set your `<img>`'s src directly. (+ Will work in all browsers)

```css
img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg" alt="a mermaid">
<img src="" alt="an img tag in alt fallback mode (inline)">
```

- Force the `display` property to be `inline-block`. (But remember the `content` will not work everywhere)

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
}

#css {
  content: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg');
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg" alt="a mermaid">
<img src="" alt="an img tag in alt fallback mode">
<img id="css" src="" alt="an other img tag in alt fallback mode, but with some image set as content through CSS">
```

Comment: Thank you! I just marked this as the accepted answer. I use this solution now: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/585 to import images and then use the "src" attribute. This solves my problem. The reason I used content: url() before was because the src for the img tag did not work, and I did not examine why, but now I realize it was because the create-react-app does not play well with the src for images as stated in that link I just shared.

Answer (score -1):

Try using class selectors in CSS. For example you are currently using IDs, why not try:

```
<img className="hello-world"/>
```

and changing the CSS accordingly!